# React testing library check amount of disabled elements

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have this component

```
render(
    <MyComponent data={[{id: 1, disabled: true}, {id: 2, disabled: true}, {id: 3, disabled: false}]} />
);
```

which renders a list with checkboxes. The ones with disabled true will be disabled in the HTML.

I want to test that the amount of disabled elements is correct (so there should be only 2 disabled).

How can I do this?

This:

```
screen.getByRole('checkbox');
```

gets me all of them. Or is there any way to check if the last one is disabled?

Answer (score 2):

Could you not get all of your checkboxes with

```
const checkboxes = screen.getAllByRole('checkbox')
```

Then fetch the disabled ones

```
const disabled = checkboxes.filter(c => c.disabled)
```

Then grab the count

```
expect(disabled).toHaveLengthOf(2)
```

If you need the last then maybe

```
expect(checkboxes[checkboxes.length - 1]).toBeDisabled()
```

(If you have [jest dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom))